# How can I make Compiz have the Genie minimize animation?

Tags: compiz

I've installed CCSM and the extra Compiz Plugins, now I want to make minimize and unminimize animations have the genie effect (aka the minimize effects on OS X). How can I do this in CCSM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `ccsm`, go to `Effects` - `Animations`. Select `Minimize Action` tab.

Double click the default effect and modify it:

[image]

[image]

Tweak `Duration` as you like.